# How to get ParseUser field when other user logged in

Tags: android, parse-platform

I created a class named "noticeBoard" that save inside notices that users wrote to noticeBoard.
The noticeBoard class contain a field "user" that save the pointer to the user that wrote the notice.

When I querying on the noticeBoard class I getting ParseUser by:
ParseUser user=noticeRow.getParseUser("user");

I can't get that ParseUser fields when **I logged in with other user**!

When I'm logged in with the user that wrote the notice I can get his fields("familyName" for example).

It looks like permissions issue.
How I give all the users permission to get user fields?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ParseQuery` and query for the user, instead of using `getParseUser`, something like:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("users");
      query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> users, ParseException e) {
            //handle callback here
    }
});
```

Then just handle the callback as you want.

Comment: I query already the parse user from parse object field! but I can't acsess is data when I'm logged in not with the user that logged in